# RTSP Streaming Server C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, streaming, rtsp

I would like to write a RTSP streaming server using C++. Multiple clients will be connected to this server for receiving the streamed data.

What I understand is that I need to do socket programming in C++ for client server architecture.

I know FFMPEG has command line support for streaming audio/video. But my requirement is writing a client server socket model in C++.

I had a look at https://www.medialan.de/usecase0001.html

I am also looking at this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEMzo59CPr8

but I am not sure if this will help me.

For streaming the audio/video data, Do i need to use FFMEPG APIs. If yes, which libraries of FFMPEG i need to use?.

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Is it on a local network or over the tinterweb?

Comment: It is on local network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I will use gstreamer RTSP server.
Gstreamer is easy to use.
I tried sample example and I was able to stream a video over RTSP.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don’t need ffmpeg to write an RTSP server.

Comment: How will I stream audio/video from RTSP server if I do not use ffmpeg?.

Comment: Read the RTPS specification, and implement it.